# Call powershell script from jscript and wait for exit

Tags: powershell, jscript

I'm doing it like this but it never ends waiting.

```
var oExec = WshShell.Exec('powershell -executionpolicy bypass -File "C:\\split.ps1" "'+inFolder+'\\'+sf.name+'" "'+outFolder+'"');
while(oExec.Status == 0)
{
    doOut("Waiting for command to finish")
    WScript.Sleep(100);
}
```

EDIT:
By trial and error I've managed to create this and it works.

```
var command = 'powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "& \'C:\\split.ps1\'';
WshShell.Exec(command);
while(oExec.Status == 0)
{
    doOut("Waiting for command to finish")
    WScript.Sleep(100);
}
```

and this works. I didn't have to do anything to powershell script. There's no exit at the end of it.

Comment: Does split set an exit code?

Comment: No it doesn't. But I tried adding exit() at the end of it and it didn't change anything.